# Distinguish user based on Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth, google-oauth

I am confused, is there any way, that I can distinguish the issuer based on Access token.

I believe both FB and Google are using OAuth 2.0 to provide access, while Twitter is using OAuth 1.0. Is there any particular way to distinguish the issuer from the token received.

[Update] I have an application which is using FB or Google to login. They might have both the sessions active at a particular time. I need to invalidate the user session based on some condition. So what the user has is two tokens. So I need to distinguish who issued which one, so the intended session can be terminated.

Thanks.

Comment: Well who gave you the Access Token?

Comment: I have an application which is using FB or Google to login. They might have both the sessions active at a particular time. I need to invalidate the user session based on some condition. So what the user has is two tokens. So I need to distinguish who issued which one, so the intended session can be terminated.

Comment: Sure, but how did the user get the token? You have the option to send the token to the issuer to validate it, eg https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken, but surely it's simply better to note where the token came from at the point it was issued.